# ag-grid: Disable sorting and filtering in the RowModel, but not the UI

Tags: ag-grid

The ag-grid I'm using gets it's data from an external datasource object. That object handles sorting and filtering of the rows and gives the ag-grid new `rowData` when it's done.

But I would still like to be able to use the filter-fields in ag-grid and click the headers to change the sorting. Only that it shouldn't do the sorting and filtering itself, but instead notify the external object.

Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to just override the `doSort` and `doFilter` of the model with dummies, but that just breaks the grid completely. Since they have no return value, I hoped they just modify the objects they get as parameters and could be skipped like this.

```js
this.gridApi.getModel().doFilter = () => {};
this.gridApi.getModel().doSort = () => {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looking at the ag-grid code some more, I think I found a solution using my original hacky approach of overriding private methods. :/

```js
this.gridApi.getModel().doFilter = function (changedPath) {
  changedPath.forEachChangedNodeDepthFirst((rowNode) => {
    rowNode.childrenAfterFilter = rowNode.childrenAfterGroup;
    rowNode.setAllChildrenCount(null);
  }, true);
};
this.gridApi.getModel().doSort = function () {
  this.rootNode.childrenAfterSort = this.rootNode.childrenAfterFilter.slice(0);
};
```